# React Native using Expo Loading Sign Issue

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, expo

I'm have started learning React Native and working on a project. But I'm facing a small issue in app.js file(Don't know exactly). I have created a text preloader but whenever I run this project I'm only able to see the preloader can't view other than that preloader.

I have add my app.js code below, please help me out with that problem.

**App.js**

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, {Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import * as firebase from 'firebase'


// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "<API-KEY>",
  authDomain: "bodytutors-61db0.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://bodytutors-61db0-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "bodytutors-61db0",
  storageBucket: "bodytutors-61db0.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "65663399714",
  appId: "1:65663399714:web:cabaa1fc311e7d8c59977b",
  measurementId: "G-PMCW2HMY8B"
};

if(firebase.apps.length === 0){
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
}

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

import LandingScreen from './components/auth/Landing.js'
import RegisterScreen from './components/auth/Register.js';


const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loaded: false,
    }
  }


  componentDidMount(){
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if(!user){
        this.state({
          loggedIn: false,
          loaded: true,
        })
      }else {
        this.state({
          loggedIn: true,
          loaded: true,
         })
        }
    })
  }
  render() {
    const { loggedIn, loaded } = this.state;
    if(!loaded){
      return(
        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
          <Text>Loading</Text>
        </View>
      )
    }
    
    if(!loggedIn){
      
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Landing">
        <Stack.Screen name="Landing" component={LandingScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={RegisterScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
    );
    }

    return(
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
        <Text>User is Logged In</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

Video reference

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1hPgQWbWmEk&t=3073s

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGGus.png)

Comment: Try to change the assignment for `this.state({loggedIn: true, loaded: true,})` to `this.setState({ loggedIn: true, loaded: true});` because you are triying to assign a new value from that props, but thats not the way to do it. Thats why you are not able to pass to the another if.

Comment: Thanks alot it's running now

Comment: Im gonna put that comment on an answer, do you mind accepting that? :D

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are triying to update a state with a "get" state.

Change

```
this.state({loggedIn: true, loaded: true,});
```

to

```
this.setState({ loggedIn: true, loaded: true});
```

The second form is the right way to update a state. Changing that, you could just pass to the other if.